# Queryset which returns only objects with a foreign key assigned.Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to find a simple way to return objects which have a foreign key assigned to each other.

For example, I have such **models.py** file:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Children(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

For my parent I create objects `family1`, `family2`, `family3`. For my children I create the objects `John` and `Stefani` which are related with a foreign key from `family1`.

What is the easiest way to create a queryset which returns only `family1` (only once, even though it has many related objects). Returns `family 1` because only for this objects exist ForeignKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a [**`.distinct()`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) at the end of your queryset. For example if you want all `Parent`s that have at least one child, you can write:

```
# Parents that have at least one child

Parent.objects.filter(children__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Or if you want to find `Parent`s that have a child with a name that starts with `Ste`, then you can query:

```
# Parents that have at least one child with a name that starts with "Ste"

Parent.objects.filter(children__name__startswith='Ste').distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is as below:

Perent object is a single parent obj.

```
Parent.child_set.all()
```

This gives you all the child of the parent.

Comment: I am not convinced that this is what the OP is looking for, if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Yes, agree but with this he is able to identify the Parents with child or not, easily with a basic conditions. I have only suggested a good way as per my knowledge.